# load and parse geojson multipoint feature into openlayers 3

Tags: jquery, geojson, openlayers-3

I am trying to load sections of a geoJSON file containing only one multipoint feature into different arrays for use in my OpenLayers app, but I can't get the load and parse code right. It's a syntax problem. My geoJSON file has this structure:

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPoint",
        "coordinates": [
        [
            243.19,
            31.81
        ],
        [
            243.05,
            31.84
        ], 
             ...

        [
            141.3,
            38.51
        ]
    ]
},
"properties": {
    "active": "12 Nov 2005 22:00 - 14 Jul 2006 22:00",
    "species": "Bluefin Tuna",
    "id": "100508400",
    "sex": "unknown" 
    "time": [
        1124432402,
        1124434321,
        ...
        1144737900
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to load the geoJSON via Ajax/JQuery and parse the multipoint coordinates into an array, the time coordinates into an array, and pull out some property values.

```
        var BT100508400Coords = [],
            BT100508400Time = [],
            id, species;

    $.getJSON('data/BT100508400.geojson').done(function (data) {
        $(data).each(function () {
            BT100508400Coords.push(data.geometry.coordinates);
            BT100508400Time.push(data.properties.time);
            id = data.properties.id;
            species = data.properties.species;
        }).done(function () {
            makeLineString(id, species, BT100508400Coords, BT100508400Time);
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log("BT100508400 multipointCoords not populated");
        });
    });
```

This attempt is close to the one I was trying here:

[Creating an array from GeoJSON file in OpenLayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936575/creating-an-array-from-geojson-file-in-openlayers-3)

But I have changed my objectives a bit, specifically, my GeoJSON file needs to hold a single multipoint feature. I just can't seem to write the syntax for a singular multipoint feature as opposed to the feature collection suggested in that answer.

Thanks much.

Comment: What is the specific error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` doesn't return a value having the `done` method. So, basically, just change the code like below:

```
    var BT100508400Coords = [],
        BT100508400Time = [],
        id, species;

$.getJSON('data/BT100508400.geojson').done(function (data) {
    $(data).each(function () {
        BT100508400Coords.push(data.geometry.coordinates);
        BT100508400Time.push(data.properties.time);
        id = data.properties.id;
        species = data.properties.species;
    })
    makeLineString(id, species, BT100508400Coords, BT100508400Time);
});
```